# Case Type field not available to add to a profile

Tags: profile, civicase

I would like to make a profile that I can use to change case types and update statuses. The Case Status field is available to add to a profile but Case Type is not. This is true in my instance (Spark) and in the demo at https://dmaster.demo.civicrm.org/.

Is this just something I have to live with or is there a way to make Case Type available for profiles?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Case Type isn't really a field it's a whole set of configuration items. I don't think you can do batch case type updates in core. There might be an extension (e.g. https://civicrm.org/extensions/webform-civicrm-integration) but I don't remember seeing if it had something for this.